# Checking call parameters from mock-object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

If I change an object, that was used as a parameter to a mock, after this mock has been called, the object in the `mock.call` changes as well. Since this sentence was super confusing, let me show you what I mean:

```
from unittest import mock

test_mock = mock.Mock()

test_parameter = ["only_entry_of_this_list"]
test_mock(argument=test_parameter)

test_mock.assert_has_calls([mock.call(argument=["only_entry_of_this_list"])])
```

works perfectly fine, just like I expected it to. But if I change the `test_parameter` after the mock has been called like this:

```
from unittest import mock

test_mock = mock.Mock()

test_parameter = ["only_entry_of_this_list"]
test_mock(argument=test_parameter)
test_parameter.append("another_entry_of_this_list")

test_mock.assert_has_calls([mock.call(argument=["only_entry_of_this_list"])])
```

I get:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(argument=['only_entry_of_this_list'])]
Actual: [call(argument=['only_entry_of_this_list', 'another_entry_of_this_list'])]
```

My question now, is if this is expected behavior, since this would make testing for iterative calls of the mock with also iteratively changing arguments difficult, as only ever the latest state of the argument is accessible.

Comment: Don't know if this is intentional or not. But you can try `test_mock(argument=test_parameter[:])` in every call to decouple.